# Not able to post a an entity that has a foreign key

Tags: api, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have made a simple project that has multiple choice questions/answers on one table and the multiple choice fillers on another table.

Here is my models
MultipleChoiceModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Quiz.Shared.Features.Questions
{
    public class MultipleChoiceModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Answer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string? Section { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    }
}
```

MultipleChoiceFillerModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Quiz.Shared.Features.Questions
{
    public class MultipleChoiceFillerModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int FillerId { get; set; }
        public string Filler { get; set; }
        public MultipleChoiceModel MultipleChoiceModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I almost never have a problem with adding a question. But when i want to add a filler along with it , the filler is either not added , or only 1 out of the 3 is added.
I have isolated my code to try and figure out why 1 filler is not adding reliably

This is the code for the post
client page component

```
    MultipleChoiceModel multipleChoiceModel = new MultipleChoiceModel();
    MultipleChoiceFillerModel multipleChoiceFillerModel1 = new MultipleChoiceFillerModel();
    MultipleChoiceFillerModel multipleChoiceFillerModel2 = new MultipleChoiceFillerModel();
    MultipleChoiceFillerModel multipleChoiceFillerModel3 = new MultipleChoiceFillerModel();



    void CreateQuestion()
    {

        multipleChoiceModel.QuestionId = 1222;
        multipleChoiceFillerModel1.MultipleChoiceModel = multipleChoiceModel;
        multipleChoiceFillerModel2.MultipleChoiceModel = multipleChoiceModel;
        multipleChoiceFillerModel3.MultipleChoiceModel = multipleChoiceModel;
        addQuestion();
        addFillers();


    }


    void addQuestion()
    {
        AddingQuestionService.AddMultipleChoiceQuestion(multipleChoiceModel);

    }
    void addFillers()
    {
        ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();
        paramList.Add(multipleChoiceFillerModel1);
        paramList.Add(multipleChoiceFillerModel2);
        paramList.Add(multipleChoiceFillerModel3);

        AddingFillerService.AddMultipleChoiceFiller(paramList);
    }
```

This is the code that handles entering the filler entity

```
 public async Task AddMultipleChoiceFiller(ArrayList MultipleChoiceFiller)
        {
            //var response = new ServiceResponse<MultipleChoiceModel>();
            MultipleChoiceFillerModel reportmodel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultipleChoiceFillerModel>(MultipleChoiceFiller[0].ToString());


             _context.MultipleChoiceFillers.Add(reportmodel);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //MultipleChoiceFillerModel reportmodel1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultipleChoiceFillerModel>(MultipleChoiceFiller[1].ToString());

            //_context.MultipleChoiceFillers.Add(reportmodel1);




            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //MultipleChoiceFillerModel reportmodel2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MultipleChoiceFillerModel>(MultipleChoiceFiller[2].ToString());

            //_context.MultipleChoiceFillers.Add(reportmodel2);
            //await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 


        }
```

Why is that one filler not always being added in?
I sometimes get an error
POST https://localhost:7214/api/Question/PostMultipleChoiceFiller 500
in the browser console

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your code, you are having 3 `MultipleChoiceFillerModel` instances that you are adding in an `ArrayList` (why not `List<MultipleChoiceFillerModel>`?). Then you call `AddMultipleChoiceFiller` with the list as an argument. However in this function you call a JSON deserializer on each of those elements one by one after you translated those to string. Why don't you simply use a `List<MultipleChoiceFillerModel>` ?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Hello, I have done it that way because thats the only way i was able to send multiple classes via post or get it was far back i cant recall. But i will try your way. I do not think this is the answer to my question though because i tried posting each class one at a time and still wasnt able to post all 3 or even 1 entity reliably. Could it be a cross origin restriction causing this?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I did the one to many relationship as shown in "Convention 1" in this documentation https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx

Comment: Ok so how does this shadow property translates into a string? Did you try checking `reportmodel.MultipleChoiceModel` value ? Secondly, can you check if `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` generates an exception.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine The exception is "ex.Message = 'ex.Message' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"

Comment: It seems to be an exception on the code handling the exception, not the code we are trying to debug.